# Как использовать url в success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

В мой ajax-запрос передается аргумент `id` из которого создается `url` для самого ajax. Итак вопрос, можно ли потом както получить созданую `url`? Если в аргументе функции `success` передавать `url`, то пишет слово:

> success

Мой код:

```js
function getData(id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/" + id + "/inventory/#730",
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data, url) {
      console.log(url);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю записать `url` в переменную, а потом использовать ее в колбеке.

```js
function getData(id) {
  var url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/' + id + '/inventory/#730';
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(url);
    }
  });
}
```